# Most useful free MOSS 2007 Utilities/libraries?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I wanted to create a list of Most commonly used free Utilities/Libraries available for MOSS

For e.g

[Smart Part](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/)

[Charts](http://chartpart.codeplex.com/)

I would like you all to help me to create a one stop shop for free utilities

Comment: Good day. I've voted to close your list - I don't think it's a proper question. Nothing personal, of course. `:)`

Comment: its not personal people always search for free utilities so this thread can become one stop shop

Answer (score 3):

[SharePoint Solution Installer](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/) - Eases installation of .WSP files

Comment: Agreed - this is a wonderful tool for deployment on production servers that don't have the development tools installed.

Answer (score 3):

[SharePoint manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) : A visual representation of the SharePoint object model that lets you create / delete list items, users, etc. Works with 2007 and 2010

[WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) : A tool that integrates with Visual Studio and speeds up development considerably, allowing you to build solutions, deploy them to the GAC and the 12 hive much faster.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Patterns & Practices - SharePoint Guidance](http://spg.codeplex.com/)

- [SharePoint 2007 (WSS & MOSS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800762.aspx#SharePointLPOverview)

Answer (score 1):

**[Starter Master pages](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/)** for SharePoint 2010 - These master pages are 'THE BEST' for creating master pages in SharePoint 2010.

**[Smart Tools](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/)**  - List of Tools which is handy for SharePoint

**[SharePoint Sushi](http://sushi.codeplex.com/)** - For SharePoint Administration

**[Fusion Charts for SharePoint](http://charts4sharepoint.codeplex.com/)** - Different types of Charts.